# Change Data Type of a Set of Entries in a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I've imported a csv file with 15 columns and 100,000+ rows into a data frame. One of the columns is 'birth' to indicate the birth year. Within the column 'birth' there are actually 3 different string type formats, those that list the date in the format '02-Aug-34', those that list its format as '29DEC1899', and lastly a blank string format ''.

I've written a script that can sort the types of 'birth' strings and then converts the ones that aren't blank into the datetime format for the given date. I use a loop that iterates through an appropriate list with the row number to replace the data frame 'birth' entry from string to datetime, basically overriding the previous value.

To go through the 100,000+ entries takes about 130 seconds. Is there a more efficient way convert the data types given the 3 different possible cases of input values? Is this completion time (130ish seconds) reasonable?

I'm very new to using pandas.

Comment: Is possible `02-Aug-15` is sometimes `2015` and sometimes `1915` ?

Comment: @jezrael no, the dates are all prior to 2000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) twice for each format and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

Also `02-Aug-15` cannot be sometimes `02-Aug-1815` or `02-Aug-1915` or `02-Aug-2015`, because not possible distinguish it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['02-Aug-34','29DEC1899','02-Aug-15','']})

#format 29DEC1899
d1 = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y', errors='coerce')

#replace last - to 19
dates = df['date'].str.replace(r'(.*)-', r'\1-19')
#alternative1
#dates = df['date'].str[::-1].str.replace('-', '91-', n=1).str[::-1]
#alternative2
#dates = df['date'].str.rsplit('-', n=1).str.join('-19')

#format 02-Aug-34
d2 =  pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%d-%b-%Y', errors='coerce')

#combine formats
d = d1.combine_first(d2)
print (d)
0   1934-08-02
1   1899-12-29
2   1915-08-02
3          NaT
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to_datetime:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

```
# Can be the same 'Date' column or different
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

You can also specify a date format with "format='%d-%m-%Y'", for example